# Вычислить скидки на продукцию

Tags: joomla, javascript

Калькулятор работает на FormCalc. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать, чтобы при заказе от 1 до 5 шт выводил 100% цену (сейчас только ее и выводит), при заказе от 5 до 10- 96%, от 10 и выше 93%.

Код шаблона:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function change() {
   document.getElementById('ch1').innerHTML='0';
}
function newdoc() {
   location.assign('http://www.бла-бла-бла');
}
</script>

<div>
<table class="formcalc">
<col class="calc-td" />
<col class="calc-top" />
<col class="calc-top" />
<col class="calc-top" />
<tr>
<td class="calc-td">
<h3>Цвета антивандальных пластин для врезного исполнения:</h3></td>
  <td class="calc-top"><img src="/images/calculator/gray.png" alt="серебристый" /><br />Серебристый<br /></td>
  <td class="calc-top"><img src="/images/calculator/black.png" alt="чёрный" /><br />Чёрный<br /></td>
  <td class="calc-top"><img src="/images/calculator/green.png" alt="зелёный" /><br />Зелёный<br /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calc-tr">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="calc-box"><h3>Бокс для накладного исполнения:</h3></td>
<td class="calc-top"><img src="/images/calculator/box.png"  alt="Бокс" />
<br />Антрацит</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="formcalc">
<tr><td colspan="2" class="calc-td">
   <fieldset><legend>
    Привратник 01C
  </legend>
  <table class="colvo">
  <tr><td colspan="2" class="calc-box"><strong>Врезное исполнение</strong>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
  <p>
    <label for="C01_gray">
      <input type="checkbox" name="C01_gray" value="флажок" id="C01_gray" />
      Серебристый</label>
      </p>
      </td>
      <td>
    <label for="colvo01Cgray">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo01Cgray" id="colvo01Cgray" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
      <label for="C01_black">
      <input type="checkbox" name="C01_black" value="флажок" id="C01_black" />
      Чёрный</label>
   </p>
      </td>
      <td>
    <label for="colvo01Cblack">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo01Cblack" id="colvo01Cblack" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
      <label for="C01_green">
      <input type="checkbox" name="C01_green" value="флажок" id="C01_green" />
      Зелёный</label>
    </p>
   </td>
      <td>
    <label for="colvo01Cgreen">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo01Cgreen" id="colvo01Cgreen" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
        <label for="BOX01C">
          <input type="radio" name="BOX01C" value="переключатель" id="BOX01C" />
          <strong>В боксе</strong></label>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td>
     <label for="colvoBOX01C">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvoBOX01C" id="colvoBOX01C" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.

    </td></tr>
  </table></fieldset>
  </td>
<td colspan="2" class="calc-td">
   <fieldset><legend>
  Привратник 02A</legend>
  <table class="colvo">
    <tr><td colspan="2" class="calc-box"><strong>Врезное исполнение</strong>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
  <p>
    <label for="A02_gray">
      <input type="checkbox" name="A02_gray" value="флажок" id="A02_gray" />
      Серебристый</label>
      </p>
      </td>
      <td> 
    <label for="colvo02Agray">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo02Agray" id="colvo02Agray" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
      <label for="A02_black">
      <input type="checkbox" name="A02_black" value="флажок" id="A02_black" />
      Чёрный</label>
   </p>
      </td>
      <td>
    <label for="colvo02Ablack">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo02Ablack" id="colvo02Ablack" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
    <p>
      <label for="A02_green">
      <input type="checkbox" name="A02_green" value="флажок" id="A02_green" />
      Зелёный</label>
    </p>
   </td>
      <td>
    <label for="colvo02Agreen">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo02Agreen" id="colvo02Agreen" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
       <tr>
      <td>
        <p><label for="BOX02A">
          <input type="radio" name="BOX02A" value="переключатель" id="BOX02A" />
          <strong>В боксе</strong></label>
        </p>
        </td>
        <td>
     <label for="colvoBOX02A">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvoBOX02A" id="colvoBOX02A" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.

    </td></tr>
  </table></fieldset> 
 </td>

</tr>

<!-- Рассчитанная стоимость -->
<tr>
<td colspan="4"  class="calc-form">Рассчитанная стоимость составляет <div id="ch1"><strong><span id="rez_disp">&nbsp;</span><input type="hidden" id="rez" name="rez" value=""/></strong></div> руб. (с учетом НДС 18%) <p><br /></p>
<p><input class="button" type="reset" name="reset" value="Отменить" onclick="change(),newdoc()" /></p>

<p><br /></p><br />
<p>Выслать заявку на e-mail: 
<input type="text" value="Введите ваш e-mail" name="mailto" id="mailto" class="validate['email']" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /></p>
<p><br /></p>

<p>Прикрепить реквизиты:  
<input type="file" name="file" value="Выберите файл" /></p>

<p><br />
{CAPTCHA}
<br />
</p>
<p><br /></p>
<p><input type="submit" class="button validate" value="Отправить заявку" /></p>
           </td>
        </tr>

</table></div>
```

Формула для расчета:

rez={colvo01Cgray}*23351.02+{colvo01Cblack}*23351.02+{colvo01Cgreen}*23351.02+{colvoBOX01C}*29109.42+{colvo02Agray}*000+{colvo02Ablack}*000+{colvo02Agreen}*000+{colvoBOX02A}*000

Comment: Ну, вы бы убрали всё лишнее из кода, а то, честно говоря, не хочется выискивать нужные куски в этой простыне.

Comment: Вот, например, первый товар:
  <tr><td>
  <p>
    <label for="C01_gray">
      <input type="checkbox" name="C01_gray" value="23351.02" id="C01_gray" />
      Серебристый</label>
      </p>
      </td>
      <td>
    <label for="colvo01Cgray">Количество:</label>
    <input type="text" name="colvo01Cgray" id="colvo01Cgray" size="5" value="0" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='0')? '' : this.value;" onblur="this.value=(this.value=='')? '0' : this.value;"  onclick="this.value='';" /> шт.
    </td></tr>
Под этот калькулятор формула итоговой стоимости записывается отдельно, не в скрипте.

Comment: Ну, а вычисления вам нужны на стороне сервера или клиента?

Comment: Не знаю, Влад. Мне нужно, чтобы когда покупатель вводил определенное количество штук, на них ставилась цена со скидкой или без, а где эти вычисления будут происходить не имею представления.